# I want to divide the two numbers read in one line

Tags: c++

I have a school assignment. But I have not implemented some of the code.
After reading the three digits a and b in one line, read this numbers in reverse.
Finally, it is a matter of comparing two readings and outputting a large number.

I implemented this in C ++, but I could not divide the two numbers read in one line.

**This is an example**

-input :

123 451

-output :

321

**This is my code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(void){
char input[8];
cin.getline(input,8,'\n');

string compare1="";
string compare2="";

// I want to parsing this input string(line) to compare1 / compare2
// but I can’t.

reverse(compare1.begin(), compare1.end());
reverse(compare2.begin(), compare2.end());

if(compare1.compare(compare2)<0){
    cout<<compare2<<endl;
}else{
    cout<<compare1<<endl;
}
return 0;
}



bool next = false;
for(int i=0; input[i]!='\0'; i++){
    if(input[i] == ' '){
        next = true;
        continue;
    }

    if(next){
        compare2 += input[i];
    }else {
        compare1 += input[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: `double a, b; cin >> a >> b; cout << a/b;`

Comment: Why don't you simply use `int`or `double` instead of `string` for the input?

Comment: What is the code after main(). Your code format is bad but the line after return 0 is all that is in main. I was going to fix the formatting but when I see invalid code like this I just leave it alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the part that you want to make

```
  bool next = false;
  for(int i=0; input[i]!='\0'; i++){
  if(input[i] == ' '){
     next = true;
     continue;
  }

  if(next){
     compare2 += input[i];
  }else {
     compare1 += input[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: Huh what? Care to explain please.

Comment: What is different between this and the code that is after `main()`??